# How can I pass my function inside my class model as a field?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm using the 3rd party library, [Django Extensions](https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions/blob/master/docs/index.rst), specifically for [AutoSlugField()](https://django-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/field_extensions.html?highlight=autoslugfield#current-database-model-field-extensions).

I want to implement their use of `RandomCharField()` in my model for my `slug` field.

```
from django_extensions.db.fields import AutoSlugField, RandomCharField 

class Post(models.Model):

    class BucketObjects(models.Manager):
        def get_queryset(self):
            return super().get_queryset()

    ...
    #unique_string = RandomCharField(length=10, unique=True)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from = models.random_string(), blank=True) 
    ...

    objects = models.Manager()
    bucketobjects = BucketObjects()

    def random_string(self):
        unique_characters = RandomCharField(length=10, unique=True)
        self.slug = unique_characters
        self.save()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.stock_list
```

`AutoSlugField` requires the `populate_from` parameter. Passing RandomCharField() like so:

```
slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from = RandomCharField(), ...)
```

Does not work:
`TypeError: 'populate_from' must be str or list[str] or tuple[str], found <django_extensions.db.fields.RandomCharField>`

So instead I want to make a function within my class that creates and saves a RandomCharField to my `slug field`.

In the model above, you can see I commented out `unique_string`, if I pass that field to my `populate_from` parameter, then everything works fine. But it seems a redundant and a waste of space to have two model fields that are exactly the same.

How can I pass my `random_string` function to my slug `populate_from` parameter whenever a `Post` is created?

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Why dont you use `populate_from = "your_model_field"`?

Comment: @JPG, wouldn’t my model then have two duplicate fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to (or can't) use the **`RandomCharField(...)`** here. But, something like this will certainly work

```
from django_extensions.db.fields import AutoSlugField,RandomCharField
import string, random


class Post(models.Model):
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from="random_string", blank=True)

    def random_string(self):
        length = 10
        return ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits, k=length))
```